# Is it possible to view another user's purchases on Steam?

Tags: steam

If so, how do I view another user's purchases on Steam?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are looking at a player's profile, there is a section called "Gameplay Stats".  At the bottom of this section you will see a link to "View all N games".  After that, just click on "All Games" to see all the games they have acquired.

Comment: That's really all the game's they've purchased mixed in with those they've been gifted, have won/unlocked in sale competitions, that are free, etc. Not *quite* the same, but probably as close as is available.

Comment: also keep in mind some game bundles adds a lot of games to the list but are purchased as 1 bundle rather than 10-20 individual game purchases

Comment: In addition to games that they've been gifted, you also won't see gifts purchased. This would be nice for trading situations if you want to see if a person actually purchased a gift item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Steamcalculator](http://www.steamcalculator.com/), but it requires the user's profile to be public.

Comment: I like how it made a $5 bundle into $110. :D Good though for a list of games - even if the prices are far off. +1

Comment: Yep, that's the problem: prices aren't kept up to date.  Otherwise it remains a good tool imho :)